# The difference between houses prices and house prices

Tags: past-tense, possessives, attributive-nouns

1. For the last one year, houses prices rise 20%.
2. For the last one year, house prices rise 20%.
3. For the last one year, houses' prices rise 20%.
4. For the last one year, house's prices rise 20%.

I would think sentence 2 is correct, but I don't know what is wrong with sentence 1,3,and 4.

Comment: I'm not sure any of them sounds correct!

Comment: #2 uses the basic form of the noun as an adjective. “House prices” are prices of houses. in #3, “houses’ prices” are also prices of houses, this time using the possessive plural. It's awkward and most people would avoid it, not least of all because it is basically indistinguishable in speech from #4, which has a number mismatch (single abstract house with multiple prices). #1 is wrong because “houses” is neither a basic-form adjective nor a properly formed possessive.

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung your comments are like answers :)

Comment: @MaulikV They're just guesses. If they help somebody get a good start on a full-fledged answer, then so be it. I'm too tired to formulate anything but comments right now. Take it and run with it!

Comment: Thanks.  I can understand why 3&4 are wrong.  But still can not differentiate between "house prices" = "prices of house". "houses prices" = "prices of houses"

Comment: Note that "for the last one year" is just as bad as "houses' prices". "For the last year" (without the "one") would be grammatically unremarkable, but in this case, it would make no sense. What you want is boatseller's version: "Over the last year".

Comment: *Houses' prices* isn't wrong, though it sounds clumsy.  There are other issues with the sentences, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you don't need "one" in "for the last one year".

Second of all, change rise to rose. Rose is past tense, while rise is present.

1) Incorrect in all cases.

2) Correct. House prices is a noun in this.

3) Correct. Houses' prices = the prices of the houses. Works better with specific houses, not so much for speaking in general.

4) Only correct for one house, and it would be stated as "for the last year, **the** house's prices rose 20%".

Answer (score 1):

You are asking about prices. What kind of prices?

> House prices

So it should be:

> 2)For the last one year, house prices *rose* 20%.

*rose* because its in the past. Also it might be better to say:

> 2)For the last year, house prices rose 20%.

because *one* would be generally understood without saying it.

1) is incorrect because *house* modifies *prices*. *houses* makes no sense as a modifier or possessive in this case.

3) and 4) are incorrect. You could say:

> 3)For the last one year, *the* houses' prices rose 20%.

...prices of more than one house.

> 4)For the last one year, *the* house's *price* rose 20%.

...price (singular) of one house.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the economic commodity of what people live in:

> Over the last year, housing prices rose 20%.

Which is equivalent to:

> Over the last year, house prices rose 20%.

3 & 4 are possessive, which one just wouldn't say except in the singular:

> Over the last year, that house's price rose 20%.